# How to use job group properties in declarative Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I want to include a job with a declarative pipeline configuration into a job group in order to receive higher build priority. It works in scripted pipelines and also for conventional jobs, but it can't get it to work with a declarative pipeline.

The snippet generator suggests something like this

```
properties([[$class: 'JobInclusionJobProperty', jobGroupName: 'Release', useJobGroup: true]])
```

When I insert it on top of my pipeline, it will run, but it looks like the setting is ignored. What am I doing wrong? Is it even possible in declarative pipelines to use `properties` at all?